# Angular 8 : modal using bootstrap not appear when I call from another component

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I make modal component that will be used by 2 other components

**in modal.component.html**

```
<div class="modal" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog" id="modal_test">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 70%;">
    <div class="modal-content">
     ......
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**in page1.component.html**

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_test" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Test</button>

<app-modal></app-modal>
```

**in page2.component.html**

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_test" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Test</button>

<app-modal></app-modal>
```

problem is only page1.component.html can call modal but page2.component.html appear just backdrop
is it about same id? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
i using ng-bootstrap 
when i want to open modal i inject NgbModal to component 

below code is my way for open and closing modal 

html : 
  <ng-template #content>
        <ng-content select="div.modal-header"></ng-content>
        <ng-content select="div.modal-body"></ng-content>
        <ng-content select="div.modal-footer"></ng-content>
    </ng-template>


----------------------------------------------------------------------

<div class="modal-header">
    <i class="fa fa-close" (click)="accept()"></i>
</div>
<div class="modal-body custom_body_modal">
    <i class="fa {{icon}} attach"></i>
    <div class="title_content">{{title}}</div>
    <p>
        {{message}}
    </p>
    <div class="btns">
        <button class="accept" (click)="accept()">{{ btnClose }}</button>
    </div>
</div>


ts:    
 constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

 open() {
          this.modalService.open(this.content, {size: this.modalSize});
          this.onOpen.emit();
    }

    close() {
        this.modalService.dismissAll(); 
      }
```